Why does Black's Vim plugin generates list of cursors?
I've been looking at the plugin implementation of Black and  I don't understand this part of the implementation
for i, tabpage in enumerate(vim.tabpages):
    if tabpage.valid:
        for j, window in enumerate(tabpage.windows):
            if window.valid and window.buffer == current_buffer:
                cursors.append((i, j, window.cursor))

vim.current.buffer[:] = new_buffer_str.split('\n')[:-1]

for i, j, cursor in cursors:
      window = vim.tabpages[i].windows[j]
      window.cursor = cursor

I get that the plugin wants to preserve the cursor position after the buffer has been replaced with the new content from Black, but what I don't understand is why the plugin iterates over all tabs and all windows instead of simple using vim.current.window.cursor. As far as I can see, the cursors list should always have a single tuple anyway, so what is the point of this iteration? Why not doing this instead?
cursor = vim.current.window.cursor
vim.current.buffer[:] = new_buffer_str.split('\n')[:-1]
vim.current.window.cursor = cursor

How could it be that the same buffer is present in different tabs/windows?


How could it be that the same buffer is present in different tabs/windows?

Nothing prevent you to have the same buffer in two different windows.
To convince you of that just run:
:edit mypythonscript.py
:1
:vertical sbuffer
:10

You'll end up with two windows containing the same buffer:

On the first the buffer is at line 1,
On the second the buffer is at line 10.


Thanks, that makes sense now, I didn't think about that. Now the code makes also sense.

Thanks for your feedback! I'm glad we could help you :-)
